# Autoplay video after hovering the cursor does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a video page and I use photos as thumbnails. I want to convert photos to video playback in .webm format. I wrote a script that, when you hover over a photo element, adds and plays a video tag.

```
$(function(){
    $('.item-image').hover(function(){ 
        $('.item-image video').remove();
        $v = $(this).attr('v');
        if ($v){
            $p = '<video src="'+$v+'" class="p" ></video>';
            $(this).append($p);
        }
        $(this).children('video').play();
    }, function(){ 
        $(this).children('video').remove();
    }); 
});
```

Unfortunately, when hovering, the autoplay does not work. You must first click in the video to play. 
I noticed that after clicking and refreshing the page, playing the video after hovering the cursor works correctly. Do you have any idea why it does not work as it should?

Comment: wrap your function into a `document.ready` function and see if that works. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I did it in $ (document) .ready (function () {..}); Unfortunately it does not work

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. 
It was enough to add a **muted** to video tag

```
<video src="URL" loop muted autoplay class="p" ></video>
```